# What is the actual issue? MySql?

Tags: mysql, ssl, netbeans

*Hello*, I have been trying to solve this problem for many days with no resolve. I am a **BEGINNER**, so dim things done for me, please. My question is what is the problem, there are many stones to turn over from my perspective. Just need to be shown in the **right direction**.

I have completely restarted my computer and uninstall the mysql at least 4x. I have invested a lot of time in trying to figure this out. **Too much time** has been put in this. So any help is truly appreciated.
The answer might be something I might not know I had to do but is **obviouse**. Like to install something.

**Computer status:**

Mac El Captain, MySQL 5.7, Netbeans 8.1, Tomcat 8.0 (told not install the latest version), Connect/J (might have not set this up correctly)

I followed these instruction https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html.
When I establishing a new connection on Netbeans, I have tested the connection and it was successful. I created a database on my Netbeans and I see it on my command line what I do show databases;

I don't think I have done anything wrong, I think I have something simply missing.

**Error Messages** When Clean and Building a project on NetBeans that has tests using mysql.

1.

> Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification. Jan 04, 2016 11:46:29 AM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh

2.

> Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES))

I want the possible problems, the direction I need to look at.

**Error Message 1.** I have not found any solution on the net yet for this, any links would be helpful.

**Error Message 2.** I have gone to every corner of the web figuring this problem out and no luck.

I have reset my password of root@localhost to root
I have flushed my privileges
I have done this every conceivable way and in a remarkable amount of times.
And whole lot of other things.
I can log in normal using mysql -u root -p and then entering my root password.

I just need need to know what doors there are and which are most likely the problem.

Here is a pic that might help: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvsag.png)

Side Question:
my.cnf file of MySql is it still a file in the new version of MySQL? I have read about it, my computer does not have it. I am assuming it was there in the older versions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've done well writing a clear question.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/cant-connect-to-simple-mysql-database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first error is complaining about an SSL connection from your Netbeans to your MySQL. It seems NetBeans's default is to use SSL. That means you have two choices:

1. Switch off SSL.  This is the better choice if your 'beans machines and your MySQL server are in the same data center.
2. Configure your MySQL with the appropriate private cert and configure 'beans with the necessary certs.

To try to do #1, your JDBC connection string (the text string telling 'beans where your MySQL server is located and how to connect to it) needs to carry a particular property value. That is, the `useSSL` property needs to have a value of `false`. If you're setting up the connection string using the glassfish GUI, you'll find a screen where you can Add.. this property as one of several to the connection string.

See Step 6 of this procedure:  https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html#prepareCommunication

Properties are easy to append to connection strings. Simply append `&useSSL=false` to the string.

Get your first error solved first, then attempt to solve the second one.

Answer (score 7):

i added `useSSL=false` and it worked

```
db.mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the connection url is `db.mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"`, 
then do `db.mysql.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useSSL=false"`