# SSL certificate warning while running a servlet based web project

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, servlets, jdbc

So I made a web app which is having MVC architecture view layer is `jsp` file, model layer is a servlet and in the control layer iam doing JDBC operations for database. so when iam doing submit on view layer request is going to servlet and servlet is passing the values to my control layer class to update it in database, but at this time getting this in eclipse console:

*Tue Aug 01 02:07:07 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.*

the database is not updating. 
whats the problem and any solution..??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590652/what-is-the-actual-issue-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Your database connection is not completing because of an updated spec in MySQL. The message `According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set.` gives you that information.

To resolve this issue, you need to either get a verified SSL certificate for your MySQL server and install it, or set the `verifyServerCertificate` property to false. The second comes at the cost of not knowing whether your connection is really secure, and because of that I would recommend the first option (not to mention there are ways to [get free SSL certificates](https://letsencrypt.com)).