# Delete a row from a database through a JSP page

Tags: mysql, jsp, ssl

I'm getting this error:

> /*Thu Apr 07 10:53:44 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.*//>

```
<a href="Delete.jsp?id=<%="cat_id"%>">Delete</a>
```

any help appriciated..im new in programming

Answer (score 1):

Make `useSSL=false` in the connection property URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_name?useSSL=false;
```

See the discussion in the qusetion [Cant connect to simple mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/cant-connect-to-simple-mysql-database) and [Hibernate Forum Discussion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1042848&view=previous)

Comment: Thanks it helps me

Comment: You are welcome. Consider do a upvote or mark as answer if you find it useful