# WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, ssl

Hello I am trying to connect to a mysql database via a java servlet using eclipse and tomcat, but I take the following error: "WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended".I added "useSSL=false?" to the connection url but still get the same error.Any suggestions? The servlet's code is :

```
package com.simpleWebApplication.servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public RegisterServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
          doGet(request, response);


          response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

          String idusers = request.getParameter("0");
          String name = request.getParameter("name");
          String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
          String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
          String birthdate = request.getParameter("birthdate");
          String workAddress = request.getParameter("workAddress");
          String homeAddress = request.getParameter("homeAddress");

          try{
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

              Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysys?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","pass");

              PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Users     values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

              ps.setString(1, idusers);
              ps.setString(2, name);
              ps.setString(3, surname);
              ps.setString(4, gender);
              ps.setString(5, birthday);
              ps.setString(6, workAddress);
              ps.setString(7, homeAddress);

              int i=ps.executeUpdate();

              if(i>0)
              {
                out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
              }

            }
            catch(Exception se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
          }

      }
```

and here is register.jsp page that is connected with the servlet.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Register New User</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="register" method="post">
 <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" width="70%">
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">User Details </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Name </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="25"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Surname </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="surname" maxlength="40"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Gender </td>
    <td><select>
 <option value="male">Male</option>
 <option value="female">Female</option>
 </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Birthdate </td>
    <td><input type="date" name="birthdate" maxlength="30"></td>
   </tr> 
 <tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Work Address </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="workaddress" maxlength="30"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Home Address </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="homeaddress" maxlength="30"></td>
 </tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
 </tr> 
 </table>
  </form>
    </body>
        </html>
```

Stack error:

```
    Wed Sep 28 08:58:53 EEST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without         server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:875)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1712)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.simpleWebApplication.servlet.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image]

Comment: You get this warning from what?

Comment: I get this warning when I push the submit button from the jsp page which is connected with the servlet.

Comment: You get this warning (1) in the server logs (2) on the browser page (3) from a browser popup (4) other?

Comment: I get it on the eclipse console  ,  on the browser page I get HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: what is mysql version?

Comment: You get this warning from what line of code? and when you are doing what exactly?

Comment: @EJP why he have created the infinite loop? check the below answer.

Comment: @VladislavKysliy its MySQL Server 5.7

Comment: @EJP I updated code. Hope that helped you more now.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad I tried your solution but the problem is with ssl.

Comment: Have you checked your access via command: mysql mysql_hostname -u username -p ?

Comment: 'You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification': So do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the line doGet (request, response);  since you don't have  get method in the example above. 
I always get this warning too with jdbc but everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wrote:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysys?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","pass";
```

Here is what I think you might need to write:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?useSSL=false/mysys?autoReconnect=true","root","pass";
```

Let me know if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to ensure you put username and password correctly.

You can check your username with the help [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.3/en/) using below command:

```
Select user();
```

You can check your port number using this command in MySQL Shell:

```
Select @@port;
```

Now You can establish connection without any SSL warning as show below:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDatabaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","pass") ;
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you have to ensure you put **username** and **password** correctly.

The error you get comes from servlet code, when you try to connect with DriverManager:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysys?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","pass");
```

If you use MySQL Workbench or another software, try in that software to check the parameters to connect your database and table.

When you get the useSSL Warning, it's just a warning. Check this question on: [Warning about SSL connection when connecting to MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But I have already done what you recommend me with no result.

Comment: Submit your project and I'll repair it for you.