# Java MySQL SSL Error

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

While trying to connect to my MySQL Database which is located on the same Computer as the Proxy, this Error occurs:

```
00:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND] Fri Sep 01 00:17:43 CEST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

Here is the Connection Settings File...

```
MySQL:
  Host: localhost
  Port: '3306'
  Database: Sad-MS-Datenbank
  Username: root
  Password: 1234567890
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

P.S. Connecting to the Database from another Computers Proxy is possible. But not from localhost.

Comment: Maybe it is helpfull to add your mysql version ?

Comment: @Riccardo -- If this isn't a duplicate, you need to show the rest of your code --  including the URL connection string

Answer (score -1):

The error message already tells you. You need to add useSSL=false to your connection string. Because your Connection File looks home-brewn it's hard to tell how to specify additional connection string parameters to it.

Comment: Downvoted, because ANYONE could have read this already answered question with great answers, and arrived at what you posted .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: I need an exact answer how to fix it, and no! - It is not duplicated...

Comment: An exact answer is impossible to be given since nobody (at least I) don't know what kind of application you've got the problem with, how that configuration file you quoted is organized and how JDBC Connection Properties can be added there. What we can tell you is that the property name is useSSL and the value is false that needs to be added.