# Apache Drill :Please retry: error (unable to create/ update storage)

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill

Hi I am unable to connect mysql to apache drill on vm.

I have used jdbc connector 5.1.45 and mysql version is 5.7.20.

Also in VM its giving warning:

[image: warning]

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from the terminal and add it as text to the question, so that it is searchable for others.

Comment: I took the error message and let Google do it's magic. Have you done this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: yup I tried this too.

Answer (score 1):

Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar connector and place it in jars/3rdparty/ folder

Modify conf/drill-override.conf to add the below line before `}`:

```
drill.exec.sys.store.provider.local.path = "mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"
```

Restart drill and try again.

Storage plugin should look something like this:

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306",
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "enabled": true
}
```