# MySQL: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. USING SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to connect to my mysql database but I'm getting the following error:

```
Thu Jun 13 11:02:30 UTC 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

I know I could get around this by setting useSSL to false, but the thing is that I already have a SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt applied onto my Ubuntu 18.04 server. How can get rid of the error (Make MySQL use the SSL certificate)?

Thank you!

Comment: You can [use SSL with server verification turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593166/1719108), if it is good enough for you.