# WSO2-Api Manager Database MySQL

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I work with Api Manager version **3.0.0** and implement database, MySQL version **5.7.28** in Ubuntu **18.04.3 LTS** in localhost with this steps:

1. In MySQL, create two databases, **shared_db** and **apim_db**.
2. Create a **new user** for MySQL and add **privileges** for the user a create in the databases, **shared_db** and **apim_db**.
3. In terminal execute this lines:

   `mysql -u **NEWUSER** -p -Dshared_db < '[API-MANAGER]/dbscripts/mysql.sql';`

   `mysql -u **NEWUSER** -p -Dapim_db < '[API-MANAGER]/dbscripts/apimgt/mysql.sql';`
4. Create a JAR with this:

   `apt-get install libmysql-java`

   In this path **/usr/share/java** execute:

   `cp mysql.jar [API-MANAGER]/repository/components/lib`
5. In [API-MANAGER]/repository/conf, the file **deployment.toml**, edit this lines:

   deployment.toml

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apim_db?useSSL=false"
username = "NEWUSER"
password = "PASS"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shared_db?useSSL=false"
username = "NEWUSER"
password = ""
```

6. Restart to server and works, BUT necessarily use this **?useSSL=false**.

So, my cuestion is: Why needs this **?useSSL=false**? In production needs this lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Using useSSL=false, the server will establish the connection with mysql without ssl. This is not a good practice for production deployments. But for local setup with no real data, you can use this. 

more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database

Comment: Thanks @Menaka for the information