# WSO2 Analytics with Username and Password

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Features:

- API manager version 3.0.0
- Analytics version 3.1.0

The scenario:

**In API Manager**

1. Change the username and password of API Manager. [API_M]/reporsitory/conf/deployment.toml

   **deployment.toml**

   ```
   [super_admin]
   username = "administracion.demomatic.com"
   password = "123456789"
   create_admin_account = true
   ```
2. Change the database of API Manager, this a steps I follow [WSO2-Api Manager Database MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672534/wso2-api-manager-database-mysql)

**In Analytics**

3. In [API-Analytics]/conf/worker/deployment.yaml

   **deployment.yaml**

   ```
   #Main datasource used in API Manager
   - name: AM_DB
     description: Main datasource used by API Manager
     jndiConfig:
       name: jdbc/AM_DB
     definition:
       type: RDBMS
       configuration:
         jdbcUrl: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apim_db?useSSL=false"
         username: wso2carbon
         password: wso2carbon
         driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
         maxPoolSize: 10
         idleTimeout: 60000
         connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
         validationTimeout: 30000
         isAutoCommit: false
   ```

   ```
   # Authentication configuration
   auth.configs:
   type: 'local'        # Type of the IdP client used
   userManager:
   adminRole: admin   # Admin role which is granted all permissions
   userStore:         # User store
     users:
      -
        user:
          username: administracion.demomatic.com
          password: MTIzNDU2Nzg5
          roles: 1
     roles:
      -
        role:
          id: 1
          displayName: admin
   ```
4. In [API-Analytics]/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml

   **deployment.yaml**

   ```
   #Main datasource used in API Manager
   - name: AM_DB
   description: Main datasource used by API Manager
   jndiConfig:
     name: jdbc/AM_DB
   definition:
     type: RDBMS
     configuration:
       jdbcUrl: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apim_db?useSSL=false"
       username: wso2carbon
       password: wso2carbon
       driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
       maxPoolSize: 10
       idleTimeout: 60000
       connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
       validationTimeout: 30000
       isAutoCommit: false
   ```

   ```
   # credentials for worker nodes
   username: administracion.demomamtic.com
   password: 123456789
   ```

   ```
   ## Authentication configuration
   auth.configs:
   type: apim
   ssoEnabled: true
   properties:
   adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
   allScopes: apim_analytics:admin apim_analytics:product_manager apim_analytics:api_developer apim_analytics:app_developer apim_analytics:devops_engineer apim_analytics:analytics_viewer apim_analytics:$
   adminServiceBaseUrl: https://localhost:9443
   adminUsername: administracion.demomatic.com
   adminPassword: 123456789
   kmDcrUrl: https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.15/register
   kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://localhost:9443/oauth2
   kmTokenUrl: https://localhost:9443/oauth2
   kmUsername: administracion.demomatic.com
   kmPassword: 123456789
   portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
   businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
   cacheTimeout: 900
   baseUrl: https://localhost:9643
   grantType: authorization_code
   publisherUrl: https://localhost:9443
   #storeUrl: https://localhost:9443
   ```

Finally STARTS to servers in this orden:

- `sh worker.sh`, Analytics Worker
- `sh wso2server.sh`, API Manager
  In this step is possible to view in terminal `INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user administracion.demomatic.com connected`
- `sh dashboard.sh`, Analytics Dashboard

All servers is **OK**, but when enter to Dashboard Page, stays loading [image]

Terminal sends

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error occurred while authorizing the access to data provider. RDBMSStreamingDataProvider. class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.getPropertyValueFromParentMap(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:408)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.getTenantId(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.assembleQuery(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:306)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.authorize(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint.onMessage(DataProviderEndPoint.java:152)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.executeMethod(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:360)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.lambda$handleTextWebSocketMessage$61(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.handleTextWebSocketMessage(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:177)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.onMessage(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:85)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.DefaultWebSocketConnectorFuture.notifyWebSocketListener(DefaultWebSocketConnectorFuture.java:52)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.notifyTextMessage(WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.java:207)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.channelRead(WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.java:157)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.UriAndHeaderLengthValidator.channelRead(UriAndHeaderLengthValidator.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**How fixed this error, because I try with username, administracion.demomatic,administracion and nothing?**

Also I tried to use of [API_M]/reporsitory/conf/deployment.toml

**deployment.toml**

```
[apim.analytics]
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
```

But sends the same error, **How used this part**?

**EDIT**
Change to version 3.0.0 of Analytics but I have to same error:

[image]

The errors sends terminal are:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error found in method : java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error occurred while authorizing the access to data provider. RDBMSStreamingDataProvider. class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.getPropertyValueFromParentMap(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:408)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.getTenantId(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.assembleQuery(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:306)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.authorize(DashboardDataProviderAuthorizer.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint.onMessage(DataProviderEndPoint.java:152)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.executeMethod(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:360)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.lambda$handleTextWebSocketMessage$61(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.handleTextWebSocketMessage(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:177)
    at org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MSF4JWSConnectorListener.onMessage(MSF4JWSConnectorListener.java:85)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.DefaultWebSocketConnectorFuture.notifyWebSocketListener(DefaultWebSocketConnectorFuture.java:52)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.notifyTextMessage(WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.java:207)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.websocket.WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.channelRead(WebSocketInboundFrameHandler.java:157)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.UriAndHeaderLengthValidator.channelRead(UriAndHeaderLengthValidator.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Also after some time, aprox 10 min, terminal of dashboard sends this error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error found in method : org.wso2.carbon.analytics.permissions.exceptions.PermissionException: Failed getting roles of the user. Unable to check permissions.
```

**EDIT 2**

After to use Analytics without database, I did tests changed to user, email, etc.

when change to user and not the password, all OK.

The errros sends when I change to password, **123456789**, in API Manager or Analytics.

Try with other password similar to, **admin_1+!!!** and OK, so I think to don't accept numbers to start of password. 
Thanks all

Comment: APIM Analytics 3.1.0 is not released yet. Did you mean 3.0.0?

Comment: I change the version Analytics to 3.0.0 also I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

API Manager 3.0.0 is not compatible with API Manager Analytics 3.1.0. To fix this issue, you need to use both [API Manager 3.1.0 beta](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/download/v3.1.0-beta/wso2am-3.1.0-beta.zip) and [API Manager Analytics 3.1.0 beta](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/releases/download/v3.1.0-beta/wso2am-analytics-3.1.0-beta.zip) versions.

PS: API Manager 3.1.0 GA is not yet released.

Comment: I change to version 3.0.0 of Analytics and I have to same error.