# How could Sqoop use SSL encryption to access MySQL

Tags: ssl, jdbc, sqoop

Currently we have a requirement to use Sqoop to establish an SSL-based connection to extract data from MySQL to HDFS. According to the relevant documents of AWS and Sqoop, we have completed the splicing of the following commands:

```
sqoop-import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://remote-db.amazonaws.com.cn:3306/TSTWOWDB?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&sslMode=VERIFY_IDENTITY&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=/home/etl/ivan/ssl/clientkeystore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=xxxxxx" \
--username "TEST_USER" --password "xxxxxx" \
--table "t_wrong_qrcodes" \
--target-dir /tmp/ivan/t_wrong_qrcodes \
-m 1
```

Among the attributes,'/home/etl/ivan/ssl/clientkeystore.jks' is the local file path of the submitted server.

After the task is started, the following error is reported: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/home/etl/ivan/ssl/clientkeystore.jks (No such file or directory)`, which seems to be because Sqoop started Map-Reduce task, but there is no such file path'/mnt/home/etl/ivan/ssl/clientkeystore.jks' on each computing node.

How to set accurate attributes, and whether there is any loss of operations?

Sqoop Version - 1.4.7

References:

1. https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-sqoop-considerations.html
2. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html
3. [Warning about SSL connection when connecting to MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now, We've solved it. Pay attention to the following three points:

- Sync trust store file, named `jks` file, to each computing nodes. If you are using Aws or other cloud services, you should put the trust store file to all nodes, including task nodes if you're using instance fleet.
- The attribute `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl` should be valid url which could start with `file:/`, for instance, `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/home/hadoop/ssl/clientkeystore.jks`
- Set attribute `useSSL` as true, or it won't transform using SSL to encrypt connection.